Getting Smooth Response between Horizontal Snapping
I currently implemented so that my Character leans in the direction he is walking on Horizontal Layer. So if he presses 'D' he leans to the right and 'A' he leans to the left.
I got that working, but: If i am in the state of leaning in on a specific side, but press the other side its snapping to 0 and then moves on leaning to the other side.
I can imagine using some Quaternion.Lerp or some Mathf. for smoothing out rotation but i don't really know how.
Here's the code:
    private void HandleMouseLook()
    {
        mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * mouseSensitivity * 5 * Time.deltaTime;
        mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * mouseSensitivity * 5 * Time.deltaTime;

        Vector2 targetMouseDelta = new Vector2(mouseX, mouseY);

        float tilt = -Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * tiltAmount; // TILTING

        // SMOOTHING AND ACCELERATION
        if (mouseSmoothing == true)
        {

            Vector3 v = transform.rotation.eulerAngles;
            currentMouseDelta = Vector2.SmoothDamp(currentMouseDelta, targetMouseDelta, ref currentMouseDeltaVelocity, smoothTime, acceleration);

            rotationX -= currentMouseDelta.y;                                           // OBEN UND UNTEN ROTATION
            rotationX = Mathf.Clamp(rotationX, -upperLookLimit, lowerLookLimit);
            playerCamera.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(rotationX, 0f, tilt);
            transform.rotation *= Quaternion.Euler(0f, currentMouseDelta.x, v.z);        // LINKS UND RECHTS ROTATION

            Debug.Log(tilt);
        }

tiltAmount is currently set to 0.7;
Meaning the Camera only tilts max. -0.7 on z or +0.7 on z.
if i am not 0 on the z axis and tilt in the opposite direction, it snappes to 0.
How do i get a smooth transition between that?

I don't understand what you mean by "but press the Camera other side its snapping to 0". I see English is not your first language but it would help if you could try to articulate this point again since it seems to be essential to the question.

Sorry forgot a Word there. So when i am currently leaning left but press D, so the opposite direction, the camera FIRST snappes to 0 and THEN leans to the right. Now i want to make it a smooth transition so it doesnt snap

Looks like you've already made it for transform.rotation by using currentMouseDelta and targetMouseDelta. How about to use same idea with tilt? create "currentTilt" field and smoothly modify it on every "HandleMouseLook()" by "targetTilt" value  (it is called just "tilt" for now). Now you can use smoothly changed "current tilt" value to rotate your camera!
